# Generating output from iterations of a loop

Tags: r, loops

So i currently have this script

```
for (i in 1:134) {

  f <- 7426+i*5

  Control <- Control[ which(Control$Photo==f & 
                            Control$Distance>0 & 
                            Control$Distance<15),]
  attach(Control)

  PhysicalModel<-function(D, Red, Green, Blue, param){
    #Left4.773540e+05
    #Left7.642514e-06;
    I0 <- 3.293789e+03; #5.253042e+05;          
    P0 <- 1.014767e-03; #3.817554e-06; 

    Fr <- 0.25*Red
    Fg <- 0.44*Green
    Fb <- 0.31*Blue;
    Br1 <- abs(-3.998730e-05)*Red*abs(param[1]);      
    Bg1 <- abs(-2.760392e-05)*Green*abs(param[1]);    
    Bb1 <- abs(-3.998730e-05)*Blue*abs(param[1]);     
    Ar1 <- abs(2.519229e-01)*Red*abs(param[1]);   
    Ag1 <- abs(2.385121e-01)*Green*abs(param[1]);    
    Ab1 <- abs(6.000000e-01)*Blue*abs(param[1]);    

    I0*(Fr+Fg+Fb) * 
      (P0 + (Br1+Bg1+Bb1)*D)*exp(-(P0 +(Ar1+Ag1+Ab1))*D -1/2*(Br1+Bg1+Bb1)*(D^2)) 

  }

  lsfunc<-function(param,Par,Distance,Red,Green,Blue){
    eta <- PhysicalModel(Distance, Red, Green, Blue, param)
    sum((Par-eta)^2)
  }

  startparam <- c(0.1)

  optval <- optim(startparam, lsfunc, NULL, method="Nelder-Mead", 
                  control=c(maxit=100,reltol=1e-200), 
                  Par, Distance, Red, Green, Blue)

  print(optval)
  print(d)
  print(f)

  Output <- data.frame()
  for (i in 1:134) { Output <- rbind(Output,c(f[i], d[i])) }

}
```

So in short i'd like to be able to get both the f and i values out in a table or txt file or even a data frame but currently the script just updates with every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a vector of data frame to save the output from the iteration. After each iteration, put the current output into that vector (or data frame).

```
output.f <- rep(NA, 134)  # define an empty vector to save the output
for (i in 1:134) {
    ....
    output.f[i] <- f
}
```